# Issue with Domain and Sub-domain under the same hosting

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain, subdirectory

I have two websites:

Main Website **www.WebsiteONE.com**

Subdomain **www.WebsiteTWO.com**

They are both on the same hosting account. On the server, their files are stored as follows:

..for www.WebsiteONE.com the files are stored in folder **public_html/**

..for www.WebsiteTWO.com the files are stored in folder **public_html/WebsiteTWO/**

Now, i noticed that you can actually access WebsiteTWO by typing
**www.WebsiteONE.com/WebsiteTWO/index.html** *(or any other file in the WebsiteTWO folder)*

Also i noticed that google indexes files from WebsiteTWO as being part of the WebsiteONE

I don't want this to happen, is there anything i can do, maybe to the .htaccess file. Or maybe you know another way.
The thing is that these sites are completely different and they have no connection with each other. Still Google indexes files from site TWO to site ONE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**public_html** is the document root for WebsiteONE.com, and anything that resides in that folder will be visible on WebsiteONE.com.

You've placed WebsiteTWO.com's document root inside **public_html** hence why it's visible on WebsiteONE.com.

To fix this simply create a new folder somewhere above (or as a sibling of) **public_html**:

```
/path/to/public_html -- all WebsiteONE.com files in here
/path/to/public_html_two -- all WebsiteTWO.com files in here
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how can i set the server to redirect to /path/to/public_html_two for the second domain?

Comment: This depends what level of access you have to the webserver. Presumably you're using apache webserver (as you mention .htaccess files) in which case you should be able to modify the `VirtualHost` configuration for WebsiteTWO.com to change the `DocumentRoot` to `/path/to/public_html_two`. For example:`

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /path/to/public_html_two
        # ... rest of your config
    </VirtualHost>`